# Getting Bad Json output when using a View in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

I am using [this](http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/source/browse/trunk/src/GoogleDataTable.cs) library to help with implementing a few visualizations using Google Chart api.

The problem is that the json that I am getting as output has & quot; in the json instead of "

Below is part of the response I am getting.

```
{&quot;cols&quot;: [{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;Year&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Year&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;number&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;Month&quot;, &quot;label&quot;: &quot;Month&quot;, &quot;type&quot;: &quot;number&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;:
```

i am using .NET4, ASp.NET MVC3 and outputting this as a view.  The code of the view is as below.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    
    

    string output = new Bortosky.Google.Visualization.GoogleDataTable((System.Data.DataTable)ViewData["ResultDataTable"]).GetJson();
    
}

@output
```

I suspect the issue is happening because I am not outputting the string in the view properly.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried

```
@Html.Raw(output)
```

?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! SO not allowing me mark an answer so quickly. Will do it.

Comment: cool :) - that worked because mvc html encodes text rendered to the page by default to protect us from script injection - to override it you need to output raw text, which is that Html.Raw() does